# If conditon to get exceeded value if it goes above threshold from file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a HTML file like this

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Threshold Limit Exceeded</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Thereshold Limit Exceeded</h1>
Below is Exceeded Count<br/><br/>

<pre>        <td id="a95" bgcolor=#FDFAF9>Service-Count-New</td>^M
    ^M
        <td id="b95" align="center"  bgcolor=#FDFAF9>3023</td>^M
</pre>

<br/>mail me at <a    href='mailto:mail@abc.com'>mail@abc.com</a>.<br>
</body>
</html>
```

I have written below code to get Count mentioned in HTML

```
f = open('q.txt', "r")
for line in f:
    if "Service-Count-New" in line:
      line1 = line
      line2 = f.next()
      line3 = f.next()
      f.close
      a = line3
      b = 500
      if b < a:
        print a
    import htmlbodymailerrormsg
```

When I execute above code the if condition is not working, Meaning If value mentioned (i.e 3023) in HTML is getting printed every time, even if it below 500. 
However if I try it on ipython it works properly but not in script.

Comment: Because `a` here is not integer. So, comparison between int and string behaved that way

Comment: What is `b`? And how can you compare a `line` with integer `500`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `a` is the full line, i.e:

```
a = '<td id="b95" align="center"  bgcolor=#FDFAF9>3023</td>'
```

First you have to extract `3023` from this string (probably using [Regexp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)). Then when you have the string `3023` you have to convert it to an integer before the if statement.

A tip for improvement:
If you are parsing html, take a look at [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) instaed. Using that you can simply select the elemtn with `id=b95` and then get the content.

Comment: Yes, With the Regexp I found the string , then converted in integr and 'if condition' works for me. However as you and @Prakash047 suggested BeautifulSoup is the proper way to parse the HTML file but I am having trouble to write the code, as I am new to python.

Comment: It's not that hard : `int(soup.find('td', id='b95').text)`

Answer (score 1):

beautifulsoup will be a great help for your problem.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
htmlData = htmlFile.read()
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(htmlData)
print parsed_html.body.find('a', attrs={'td':'b95'}).text
```

use `with` file open if you have large html data.